# CSS3 Set Box Shadow to aslope corner

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I'm coding some fancy stuff for teaching myself.

I have an aslope left corner. Now, i want to add the box shadow and it showed like the following image:

[image]

This is my code snippet:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  position:relative;
  content:""; 
   border-left: 300em solid #454545;
   border-bottom: 120px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 23px 4px black;
}


.under-bar {
    margin-top: -40px;
    background: #851e39;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.8
}

<html>
   <body>
        <div class="navbar">

        </div>
        <div class="under-bar">
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me to set a box-shadow under the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform: rotate();` instead of the border tricks.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #9d4b61;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 23px 4px #000;
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  background-color: #333;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="menu">menu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. But if i want add some control like Button or a tags, they are under the aslope div. How can i put them in der foreground ?

Comment: @Mo_Code Just like I did in the demo above, wrap them into a div and set position relative to increase the stacking order, it should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `border-radius` and `transform: scale`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #9d4b61;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #5c5c5c;
  border-radius: 0 0 100%/22px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 23px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  transform: scale(1.1,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

The `border-radius: 0 0 100%/22px 0` set a radius in the bottom right corner, which is 100% wide and 22px height, giving the radius a "stretched" look.

The `transform: scale(1.1,1)` is stretching the entire element, to hide the box-shadow in each side.